# Hidden layers appear when I hit undo

Tags: outliner

I have two layers that have a purple circle around the visiblity "eye" icon in the outliner.  Every time I hit undo, these two purple layers re-appear.  How do I mark them as un purple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you somehow added a driver to an object on one of the layers. Simply right click the eye and choose *Delete Driver*. It is an undoable action so if you undo, it will revert so you might want to save the file and reload it.

Comment: @portforwardpodcast Normally just adding a driver shouldn't do anything but it seems like you have something else going on for it to be messing with your scene.